# Django and UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, utf-8, decode

**What i do...**

___I have an upload form from where i upload .zip files with pictures. And everytime when there is a file title with some non-ascii character äüõ  i get a unicode decode error.

```
 title = ' '.join([filename[:filename.rfind('.')], str(count)])
```

**Error:**

This line generates the title of the picture , and that is exactly the line that gives me error:  `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 2: invalid start byte. You passed in 'cr\x82ations' (<type 'str'>)`

**What i tried to do:**

I tried to  `.decode('utf-8')` it too. But get the same result everytime no matter what i try.

I read about changing default djangos ascii to utf-8 in site.py  , but am not sure it will help , and pretty sure that i don't want to do it.

**ANy help is appreciated.**

Comment: You should use `decode()`, yes, but are you sure it's UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Django has some useful utility methods which you can use.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions

I imagine the code might look something like this:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

title = ' '.join([smart_str(filename[:filename.rfind('.')]), str(count)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I also believe firstly using .decode() is the right option, however, the code page ('utf-8')) you used might incorrect. Can you have a try '1252' or some others? Here are some standard encoding you might interest [Link]http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html?highlight=arabic

Answer (score 0):

The reason this fails, is because you try to join with a normal `str` object:

Instead of

```
' '.join(..)
```

use:

```
u' '.join(..)
```

Or make your life easier using:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```